# Cannot access config file variables in bash script function

Tags: bash, function, shell, variables, config

I have one config and one main bash script files. Config file has variables assigned with values whereas, the main file wants to access them. Below are my files,

> config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

username=abc
password=abc
hosts=(192.168.110.164);
walletname=varsh
```

> main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/shell/config.sh

echo "$username"
echo "$walletname"

start_block(){
  echo "$username"
  echo "$walletname"
}

SCRIPT="$(declare -f); start_block"
for i in ${!hosts[*]} ; do
        printf "\t=========== Logging in ${hosts[i]} ===========\n\n"
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${password}}
        sshpass -p ${password} ssh -l ${username} ${hosts[i]} "${SCR}"
done
```

`$username` and `$walletname` can be accessed from outside of the `start_block` function but not from inside the function. The echo from the function `start_block` gives empty results. I tried using `export` before variable names in config. How can I access these variables?

Edit:

I want to login to another host using the username password, create some files, run installation and other commands using config file variables. And there could be many variables in the config.

Comment: From taking a quick look at your code, it does not look like `start_block` is being executed anywhere in the script

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by `SCRIPT="$(declare -f); start_block"`

Comment: ok, I see: SCRIPT gets a list of ALL functions defined (i.e, `ftn_1() {...}; ftn_2() {...}; ...`) and then you try to search/replace all instances of PASSWORD with the variables in the config. Note: currently, `SCR` will only replace the first instance, to replace all, you'll need `SCR=${SCRIPT//PASSWORD/${password}}` (two slashes). But I don't know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Second, I don't see how any of the config variables are going to be used in `$SCR` (or `$SCRIPT` for that matter). (As already mentioned.) There might be a way to accomplish what you're trying to do here, but it seems like a really fragile way to implement variables in a shell script (i.e, global search & replace based on pattern). (rest of comment deleted, doesn't work).

Comment: This is the working code for `ssh` and `script`.  Logging in `${!hosts[*]} ` is not the issue.  `start_block` function is also getting executed (tested with printing some string inside function).

Comment: only the variables are not getting accessed within the function `start_block`

Comment: I think I can figure out what you are trying to do here, but really, this is massively obscure. Please [edit] to explain what you want to happen and why you have chosen this decidedly unorthodox approach. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are not sent to the remote host. You can forcibly inline them, like you do the functions:

```
SCRIPT="$(env) ; $(declare -f) ; start_block"
```

I'd, however, recommend just inlining the config directly:

```
SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $(declare -f); start_block"
```

Comment: I want to send the functions also. Can I inline the file itself. eg. `SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $(cat ~/shell/main.sh) ; $(typeset -f) ; first"`? This pass the functions but give error first ```bash: line 28: /home/remotehost/shell/config.sh: No such file or directory
cat: /home/remotehost/shell/config.sh: No such file or directory
cat: /home/remoteost/shell/main.sh: No such file or directory```

Comment: The error is saying that your cat commands are running remotely (they should run locally). I can't say more without seeing the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

The function is executed, when you do a `ssh -l ${username} ${hosts[i]} "${SCR}"`. Hence it is executed in a separate process, most likely even on a different host. Of course you don't see your shell variables over there. Actually it is surprising that on the remote side, `start_block` does not give raise to a *command not found* error, since the function also exists in your local process only.

As for the variables, you could turn them into environment variables (by using the `export` command) and use the `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` options in your ssh configuration file, as explained for instance [here](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command).

Comment: The `declare-f` inlines all the local function definitions so they are also declared remotely.